# Change select element options according to its identifiers react

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, select

New react developer i'm learning by coding,

Here i have 'country' and 'city'.
There could be many more country or city boxes, each those 'country' has its own identifier and each city has its own city_id.

I need advice/help on this:
if user is changing one of those country boxes (from its select dropdown), then it should only affect those city boxes which is connected to it (these two has same value so they are connected identifier: "0-0-0-4" and city_id:"0-0-0-4"), others should stay to default. (one country box can be connected to many city boxes so there could be for example two city boxes with same city_id:"0-0-0-4")
In my code 'country' are in different component and cities in another

my code:
try it here codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-cascading-select-forked-6lt4g0?file=/src/App.js

```js
  const city = useSelector(
    (state: RootStateOrAny) => state.selection.city
  );
 
 const country = useSelector(
    (state: RootStateOrAny) => state.selection.country
  );
  
  that country contains : {identifier: "0-0-0-4",type:""}
  
  that city contains: {city_id:"0-0-0-4",mode:"hereShouldbeThatType"}
```

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const countriesData = [
  {
    name: "Germany",
    states: ["Duesseldorf", "Leinfelden-Echterdingen", "Eschborn"]
  },
  {
    name: "India",
    states: ["Delhi", "Kolkata", "Mumbai", "Bangalore"]
  },
  {
    name: "France",
    states: ["Auvergne", "Bretagne", "Corse", "Centre"]
  }
];

function Form() {
  const [{ country, state }, setData] = useState({
    country: "Germany",
    state: ""
  });

  const countries = countriesData.map((country) => (
    <option key={country.name} value={country.name}>
      {country.name}
    </option>
  ));

  const states = countriesData
    .find((item) => item.name === country)
    ?.states.map((state) => (
      <option key={state} value={state}>
        {state}
      </option>
    ));

  function handleCountryChange(event) {
    setData((data) => ({ state: "", country: event.target.value }));
  }

  function handleStateChange(event) {
    setData((data) => ({ ...data, state: event.target.value }));
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={() => console.log("Submitted")}>
      <div className="all">
        <div>
          <p>Countries</p>

          <div className="leftBox">
            Box 1 type
            <select value={country} onChange={handleCountryChange}>
              {countries}
            </select>
            <input type="submit" />
          </div>
          <div className="leftBox">
            Box 2 type
            <select value={country} onChange={handleCountryChange}>
              {countries}
            </select>
            <input type="submit" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <p>cities</p>
          <div className="rightBox">
            Mode
            <select value={state} onChange={handleStateChange}>
              {states}
            </select>
          </div>
          <div className="rightBox">
            Mode
            <select value={state} onChange={handleStateChange}>
              {states}
            </select>
          </div>{" "}
          <div className="rightBox">
            Mode
            <select value={state} onChange={handleStateChange}>
              {states}
            </select>
          </div>{" "}
          <div className="rightBox">
            Mode
            <select value={state} onChange={handleStateChange}>
              {states}
            </select>
          </div>{" "}
        </div>{" "}
      </div>
    </form>
  );
}

export default Form;
```

English is not my mother language so could be mistakes.

Comment: any help is appreciated

Comment: Here you go: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-cascading-select-forked-5nzssf?file=/src/Form.js

Comment: @ChrisG added more information to question, that identifer comes from redux so cant put it like this what u have done: const [data, setData] = useState({
    "0-0-0-4": { country: "Germany", cities: ["", ""] },
    "0-0-0-5": { country: "Germany", cities: ["", ""] }
  });

Comment: i should be able to dispatch selected value from select dropdown like this dispatch(editCities({identifier: "0-0-0-4",type:"India"}))

Comment: @ChrisG any idea?

Comment: Of course I do, but have you tried anything so far? My fork shows how to use components for the boxes and handle changes, putting this in redux format is a small step from there.

Comment: I just know redux toolkit, but with this project what im working i need to use older redux (switch case’s)